# Caching page after ajax loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, back-button

I am using Jquery Ajax to load more content to my page when user scroll to the bottom of page, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      $.ajax({
        url: /* my url goes here */,
        cache: true,
        success: function(html){ /*append html to the bottom of page*/ }
      });
    }
});
```

The problem is that: when user press some link in my page then press the back button, the new content that loaded before disappear. How to keep the new content? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the back button is clicked, the page is returned to the original state stored in the browser history. Ajax tends to "break" the back button.

You could save some a flag in your session to say what content you loaded via ajax on the last view. When the page reloads you can check with the server what the previous page state was.

Alternatively change the fragment identifier when you do an ajax call using: `window.location.hash( "new-url-hash" )`. You'll still need to do an initial check with your javascript to see what the fragment id part of the url is. If you change any other part of the `location` property the page will reload.

HTML5 adds in the `pushState()` method to change the browser history. See the mozilla docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). `pushState()` does not cause the page to reload.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I've solved this problem by using SESSION. Anyway, thanks for your answer :D